# How to solve infinite redirection in Vuejs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

I created a store that stores the current user. The application must not allow going on any page if the user is not logged in, so I created a method that checks if the user is logged in, and if not it should redirect the page to the login page but I got an infinite redirection.

This is the user store:

```
import router from "@/router";
import axios from 'axios';
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ApplicationConstants } from '../utils/Constants';
import { UserStoreState } from "./UserStoreStateI";
import { Role } from '@/Types/Role';


export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
    state: (): UserStoreState => ({
        currentUserId: -1,
        currentUserUsername: "",
        currentUserRoles: [],
        isLoggedIn: false
    }),
    getters: {
        getCurrentUserId: (state) => state.currentUserId,
        getCurrentUsername: (state) => state.currentUserUsername,
        getCurrentUserRoles: (state) => state.currentUserRoles,
        isUserLoggedIn: (state) => state.isLoggedIn,
        hasRole: (state) => { return (role: Role) => state.currentUserRoles.includes(role);} 
    },
    actions: {
        logIn(username: string, password: string) {
            const authDTO = {
                "username" : username,
                "password" : password
                }
                const loginResponse = axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: ApplicationConstants.API_LOGIN_URL,
                    data: authDTO
                }).then((loginResponse) => {
                    /** Set JWT access token in LocalStorage. */
                    const token = loginResponse.headers["access-token"];
                    localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token);
                    /** Set current user credentials. */
                    this.currentUserId = loginResponse.data.id;
                    this.currentUserUsername = loginResponse.data.username;
                    this.currentUserRoles = loginResponse.data.roles;
                    this.isLoggedIn = true;
                    /** Go to Home page. */
                    router.push("/");
                }).catch((error) => {
                    
                });
        },
        logOut() {
            this.$reset();
            router.push("/login");
        }
    },
    persist: true
});
```

And here are the routes and the restriction functions:

```
const goToLoginIfNotAuthenticated = (to: RouteLocationNormalized) => {
    const userStore = useUserStore();
    const isUserLoggedIn = userStore.isUserLoggedIn;
    
    if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
        return 'login';
    } else {
        return to.fullPath;
    }
}
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: HomeView,
        meta: {requiresAuthentication: true},
        beforeEnter: [goToLoginIfNotAuthenticated]
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: LoginView
    }
]
```

In LoginView I have a LoginForm component, but the redirection to the Home page is done only when the form is submitted.
I am using Vue3 with Composition API, Pinia and Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive redirection comes from

```js
if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
    return 'login';
} else {
    return to.fullPath;
}
```

When you're on `login` and not `isUserLoggedIn` you again redirect to `login`.
Just add another check:

```js
if (!isUserLoggedIn && from.name !== "Login") {
    return 'login';
} else {
    return to.fullPath;
}
```

`from` you can get from hook signature: `(to, from, next)`